# Why did the Tos'fos Yom Tov compose his Mi Sheberach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, provenance, acharonim, mi-sheberach

It is well known that R. Yom Tov Heller, author of the *Tos'fos Yom Tov* and other works, wrote a prayer to be recited for the benefit of those who don't speak in the synagogue (or: during prayer). I'm trying to find his expression of the reason he composed it or wanted it recited, or a reliable second-hand source citing him. I do see many hundredth-hand sources online, but seek something more reliable than that. I'd appreciate any direction.

Comment: Perhaps because a lot of people in his shul talked during prayer, so this was a kind of "bribe", so to speak. When people saw how respected are the non-talkers, it might convince them to act the same.

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=7665

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%22%D7%97%E2%80%93%D7%AA%22%D7%98

Comment: similar https://seforimchatter.buzzsprout.com/1218638/6599569-with-prof-joseph-davis-discussing-the-tosfos-yom-tov-rav-yom-tov-lipmann-heller-zt-l?play=true

Answer (score 5):

Another image of this appears in the link that @interested posted. It's a Slichot for 20th of Sivan, printed around 1650, [apparently by the Tosfot Yom Tov himself](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=16335#p153619), brought in [Otzar Hachochmah](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=16&book=147328):

[image]

It's hard to read, but I think it says:

> "גם מיד כשנודע פה ק"ק קראקא יא?בם הגזירה רעה ??? ?? ק"ק נעמרוב הגדולה אז כדי להסיר מכשול העון הגדול של שיחה שבבית [הכנסת] שהפ?? אוסרו מקל וחומר לעומד בבית מלך בשר ודם ייסד גאונינו יצו הנ"ל מי שבירך כו שיאמרוהו החזן מידי שבת בש[בת] בקול רם ראיתי כי [טיב?] הדפיסו גם כאן לזכות בו גם שאר הק"ק ואין ספק שרבים יהיו נמנעים מלענות [עוד] [להשוחד] איסור הגדול הזה ואקבל בזה שכר המזכה את הרבים כו"

Translation: And also when it was reported here in the holy community of Krakow [????] the evil decree ??? ?? the holy community of Greater [Nemrov](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11437-nemirov) so to remove this terrible stumbling block of the great sin of speaking in synagogue that the ?? prohibits with a kal v'chomer from one who stands in the house of a flesh and blood king founded our gaon [not sure how to translate this] mentioned previously a Mi Sheberach etc that the chazan will say every Shabbat and Shabbat in a loud voice I saw that [???] printed here too to reward also the other holy communities and there's no doubt that many will refrain from answering [any more] [to the bribe] of this great sin and I shall receive by this the reward of he who entitles the public."

Even if this wasn't printed by the TY"T himself, it was surely under his guidance, because [at the time he was Rabbi of Krakow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom-Tov_Lipmann_Heller#Education_and_rabbinic_career). The evil decree referred to here is of course [the Khmelnitsky Pogroms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cossack_riots) (גזרות ת"ח ות"ט). It seems the TY"T saw a connection between talking in shul and the pogroms.

Another source, albeit about a century or so later, is in the booklet "[Mora Mikdash](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3725&st=&pgnum=5)" by [Rabbi Yaakov Yosef of Ostra'ah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94):

> "לכך נדפס בשם תוספות יום טוב לעשות מי שבירך בכל שבת ושבת למי שאינו מדבר בבית הכנסת דברים בטלים, תיכף אחר סליחות של עשרים בסיון, שחיבר תוספות יום טוב בשביל המעשה שנהרגו רבבות מישראל בשנת ת"ח, אמרו למעלה בשביל שדיברו בבית הכנסת ובבתי מדרשות ונתחייבו שונאיהם של ישראל דבר שפגמו הוי"ו של דבור ונעשה דבר, ובשביל שעשו גם שאר עבירות היה רציחה הרחמן הוא יצלינו."

Translation: For this it was printed in the name of the Tosfot Yom Tov to make a Mi Sheberach on every Shabbat and Shabbat for whoever doesn't speak in synagogue nonsense, immediately after the Slichot of the 20th of Sivan, that the Tosfot Yom Tov authored for the event in which tens of thousands from Yisrael were killed in the year 408, They said up there that it was because they spoke in the synagogue and in the batei midrashot and the haters of Yisrael were found guilty for impairing the Vav of Dibur and became Davar, and also for committing other sins came the murder, the Merciful shall save us."

About a century after that, Rabbi Ahron Marcus, while not directly referring to the Mi Sheberach, wrote in his book "Hachassidut", pg. 24 ("Der Chassidismus" in the original German):

> "הגאון בעל "תוספות יו"ט" הנזכר לעיל, ערך לאחר השואה שאלת חלום. מתוך סגופים קשים התפלל, כי יגלו לו מן השמים בשל מה באה הגזירה הרעה. ענו לו: בגלל התנהגות של קלות ראש בבית הכנסת ושיחות בשעת התפילה."

Translation: "The Gaon author of "Tosfot Yo"T" mentioned above, made after the holocaust [a reference to the Khmelnitsky Pogroms] a dream-question. Out of great ascetics he prayed, that it would be revealed to him from Heaven for what [reason] came this terrible decree. They answered him: Because of the frivolity in synagogue and speaking during prayer."<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> In [the introduction](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1682&pgnum=10) to his commentary on Shut Min Hashmayim, he gives his source to this as being Rabbi Yaakov Yosef of Ostra'ah's book.

Comment: +1. "שהפ?" Might be "שהם". Also בש[בת] might actually be בש[בתו]. And טיב[?] הדפיסו might be טיב (טוב?) להדפיסו